# Dealing with categorical missing values represented by bins in Python?

Tags: python, missing-data, categorical-data, imputation, bins

I have a dataset with some missing data. The missing data is categorical and represented by bins (please, see example below: 'purchase_price', 'customer_income', etc.). **What is the best approach for imputing data like this?** Should I transform the bins first? Somehow, cannot find any recommendations online.

| purchase_price | trade_in | vehicle_finacing | customer_age | customer_income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15001-20000 | 1 | 1 | 21 - 30 | 40001-60000 |
| 15001-20000 | 0 | 0 | 51-60 | 0-20000 |
| 25001 - 30000 | 1 | 1 | 41-50 | 60001-80000 |
| 10001 - 15000 | 0 | 1 | 21-30 | 60001-80000 |
| 25001 - 30000 | 1 | 1 | 31-40 | 120000-140000 |

Comment: Try to divide the bin columns into 2 separate columns ex: purchase_price_start and purchase_price_end then try to impute the each column seperately

Comment: Ill recommend to impute each seperate columns with median or try to remove the row itself if your dataset is large enough.